# Why do Smith numbers have to be composite numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, arithmetic

As you may know, a Smith number is a number that if all the digits are added together that answer is equal to the sum of its prime factors' digits.

Why are 2 and 3 not Smith numbers?

Comment: Because of the definition? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_number)

Comment: I understand that @Thomas but two and three both fit all the credentials except for the fact that they are prime numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smith numbers appeared in 1982 when Albert Wilansky "published" an "article" in the *The Two-Year College Mathematics Journal*. The article is really short and just gives the definition and an example and some questions. According to the definition a Smith number is a *composite* number. Wilansky came across the numbers because he noticed his brother-in-law's (named Smith) phone number $4937775$ is a Smith number.

As a mathematician Wilansky probably immediately had questions. How many Smith numbers are there? Specifically he wondered in the "article" if the phone number is the largest Smith number. He then probably thought about it and realized that interesting problems come from these numbers. Now, if your definition says that prime numbers are Smith numbers, then you have already answered the question about how many there are. So instead of saying "Smith numbers that are not prime" every time, he simply required the number to be composite in the definition.

If you want to read more about this, you can take a look at a couple of articles (if you are at a university, you should be able to find these)

- *Smith Numbers*, Underwood Dudley, Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 67, No. 1 (Feb., 1994), pp. 62-65
- *The Sum of Digits Function and its Application to A Generalization of the Smith Number Problem*, Wayne McDaniel, Samuel Yates, Nieuw Archief Voor Wiskunde, 7, No, 1-2, March/July, (1989), 39-51.

Comment: I do not believe that if the definition says prime numbers as well, that would not answer the question how many smith numbers there are as there are indeterminably more numbers that are not prime that are smith numbers.

Comment: @theunie" I said: " if your definition says that prime numbers are Smith numbers, then you have already answered the question about how many there are". You know that there are infinitely many prime numbers. If any prime number is a Smith number, then there are infinitely many Smith numbers.

Comment: Yes I understand that but there will then be indeterminably more numbers other than the prime numbers.

Comment: @theunie: You are missing my point: the questions you can ask are more interesting if you do not say that prime numbers are smith numbers.

Answer (score 2):

All prime numbers fulfill the sum-of-digits-condition, and are therefore relatively uninteresting in this context. Hence, the Smith numbers are specified to be non-prime.

Another way of looking at it is: All prime numbers fulfill this condition. What *other* numbers do so? The Smith numbers is the answer.